# Arduino Mega & WiFi Shield; why web server every time says my A7 pin reads 0V?

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, wifi, web-server, web-service

I have got Arduino Mega 2560, Arduino WiFi Shield and resistor 1.5K.

Now PWM 2 is attached to the resistor then attached GND. 5V is attached between PWM2 and resistor's up point. I want to read the Arduino Mega's A7 analog input point in order to print this value on an Android Phone's web browser but, I get zero value every time surprisingly. It should be like 235, 350 something like integer or float kinds as usual.

According to Android Phone's Google Chrome Web Browser Page, why there are too many zeros in the HTML? It should be different from zeros because I have already added a short wire to Analog A7 so as to make an antenna.

A photo of my setup:

[image: My workside]

Screenshot of my Android web browser

[image: Android Phone Screen]

Serial Monitor output

[image: Arduino IDE & Serial Monitor]

My code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "Connectify-me";      
char pass[] = "***";    
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
float PPG = analogRead(A7);
boolean door_status = false;
WiFiServer server(80);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Yazdigin SSID araniyor: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  } 
  server.begin();
  printWifiStatus();
}
void loop() {       
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("Deger gonderildi");
    Serial.print(PPG);
    while (client.connected() & client.available()) {
          client.println("<html>");
          client.println("<body>");
          client.println("<li>");
          client.print(PPG);  //The value should different from zeros but everytime 0
          client.println("</li>");
          client.println("<br />");
          client.println("</body>");
          client.println("</html>");
      }
    }
    delay(3000);
      client.stop();
      Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
  void printWifiStatus() {
  Serial.print("Baglandigimiz SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Addressi browserda ac: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
}
```

Comment: Step 1 in troubleshooting is to create a minimal example. The `Serial.print(PPG);` shows 0, so all the web server stuff is irrelevant. You need to narrow your scope to isolate the problem.

Comment: Use images that add information to you question. A screendump of the code and a screendump from 0-values doesn't add to the information, it even distracts. A proper circuit diagram would normally be welcome, but after analyzing your writing and the picture I concluded that all this question  is about, is a dangling wire. Don't put up a smoke screen, as sachleen mentioned, it is very important to narrow down to what you actually want to know and that is not limited to minimal code to reproduce the issue. It took me several minutes (and considering to leave the question unanswered) to understand

Answer (score 2):

The capacitor in the sample-and-hold circuit in the ADC frontend is tied to ground and it is *very* leaky. Unless you have a low or medium impedance output connected to it, you will always read the ground value. An antenna is a *very* high impedance device.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the input pin `float PPG = analogRead(A7);` only in the startup code of your program. Move that into the loop to have it updated before using it.

Comment: Yes, I have already did this. Still, not a remedy for me.